# Using mod_rewrite with chinese characters in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, special-characters

I am having trouble finding information on Apache mod_rewriting using Chinese characters (all the info I can find relates to numbers).

I want to rewrite `/character.php?character=宠` (where the character is the result of a search and thus will vary) to `/character/宠`.

This is my (poor) attempt: 
`RewriteRule    ^character/?$    characters?character=$1    [NC,L]`

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your Regular Expression is incorrect. Using the `?` tells `mod_rewrite` that the character before it is optional. It is not a placeholder for any character.

You should be doing this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^character/(%[A-Z0-9]{3})$ characters?character=$1 [NC,L]
```

This rule assumes you want to only capture one character. If this is not the case, or you need the same rule elsewhere, then swap out `(%[A-Z0-9]{3})` for `(%[A-Z0-9]+)`.

You also need to make sure that your `.htaccess` file is saved in Unicode format (UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks you. However, I am still having problems. I am getting an `Object not found!` error. This is my code (which is in the same folder as all the .php files): `RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^character/([^./]{1,1})$ character?character=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Chinese characters in URL usually transfer as percent-encoding string as "%E5%AE%A0" (=宠) format so you have to change the rule `[^./]{1,1}` (one UTF-8 Chinese character usually encoding as 3 bytes so the format will be %[A-Z0-9]{3})

Comment: Thanks for that, @hit1205 - was not aware of how that works. Not a unicode fanatic. I will update my answer.

Comment: You're welcome =D
By the way, I found the format I wrote has a little typo, it should be `(%[A-Z0-9]){3}`

Comment: I have used `RewriteRule ^character/(%[A-Z0-9]){3}$ character?character=$1 [NC,L]` and it still isn't working :(

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^character/(%[A-Z0-9]){3}$ character.php?character=$1 [NC,L]` - I think that the `.php` should be there, as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^character/(.+)$ /characters?character=$1 [NE,NC,L,QSA]
```