# mod_rewrite rewrite url with japanese characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good morning!

I have a RewriteRule that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(search)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sw=$2
```

Sometimes my "sw" will contain japanese characters, for example "こんにちは". If someone searches with jap characters the rewriterule won't rewrite obviously.

But how should the rule look?

Something like:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9あ-わ]+) ??
```

This still wouldn't work with Kanji but only Hiragana even if it worked.

Help please. Thank you!

Comment: I've not done this before, but it looks like the trick is that mod_rewrite will get the characters in a url-encoded format, so what you'd be matching is `%[A-Z0-9]`. This might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127162/using-mod-rewrite-with-chinese-characters-in-apache

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this:

Instead of using `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`, use `(.+)`. Now any characters at all should be read.